# Get the nth-child of the exact same node?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a "node signature" that will return a node like the following :

```
div.container>div.row:nth-child(1)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(2)
```

I'm close to finish it, I just have the following issue :

The `nth-child` value only takes into consideration if the node is the same (nodeName) but since there is an ID on that node, and some class, the selector fails to be correct because in that case, there is only one div#clients, not multiple. (even though at the same level, there is many div).

Here's the code :

```
function getPath(e) {
    var path = [];
    if ('path' in e && e.path.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.path.length; i++) {
            if (e.path[i]) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(e.path[i]));
            }
            if (e.path[i] === document.body) break;
        }
    } else {
        var node = e.target;
        while(node != document.body) {
            if (node) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(node));
            }
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }

    path.reverse();
    return path.join('>');
}

function getNodeSignature(node) {
    var structure = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if ('id' in node && node.id) {
        structure += '#' + node.id
    }

    var classes = null;
    if ('classList' in node && node.classList.length > 0) {
        classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.classList);
    } else if ('className' in node && node.className) {
        var classes = node.className.split(/\s+/);
    }

    if (classes !== null && classes.length > 0) {
        structure += '.' + classes.join('.');
    }

    var position = getIndexInParent(node);
    if (position > 0) {
        structure += ':nth-child(' + position + ')';
    }

    return structure;
}

// The following code doesn't take into consideration the ID and class path
function getIndexInParent(node) {
    var children = node.parentNode.childNodes;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i]==node) return num;
        if (children[i].nodeName == node.nodeName) num++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And here's an HTML example :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In that case, the code should return the following, if you click on the second `.row`, third `div`:

```
div.container>div.row:nth-child(1)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(0)
```

(nth-child should be 0, not 3, since the previous indications, "div" and ".list.col-md-6" are enough to reduce the possibilities to 2 items)

**Example** : https://jsfiddle.net/an2jsq2r/1/

If you click on the second items, on "Item 3", you'll get :

```
body>div.container>div.row:nth-child(1)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(2)
```

Which is wrong, because it should be :

```
body>div.container>div.row:nth-child(1)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(0)
```

(notice the `div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(0)`). The code doesn't take into consideration the restrictions added by potentials IDs and Classes to count the position of the element.

How can I do ? (Note: I need to be the broadest possible, by supporting the maximum range of browsers).

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: *"no nth-child since the previous indications, "div", "#clients" and ".list.col-md-6" are enough to reduce the possibilities to 1"* Just `#clients` does that, you don't need `.list.col-md-6` or `div` unless you want to ignore the one existing `#clients` element if it's not a `div` or it doesn't have the class `.list.col-md-6`. (Assuming a valid document.)

Comment: In my given example, yes, but if you take the fourth div element, making div.list.col-md-6 won't be enough. Also I need to anticipate the case where the html is invalid and contains two same IDs. (since it's for general use)

Comment: Okay. Note, though, that you're already relying on document-specific context if you're saying you don't need the `:nth-child(3)` on `div#clients.list.col-md-6` to differentiate it from the other children in its parent. So using context to determine whether an ID is unique would also be reasonable. Just FWIW.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. It may be because you have a misunderstanding of `:nth-child` (or may not). You've said *"but since there is an ID on that node, and some class, the selector fails to be correct because in that case, there is only one div#clients, not multiple"* but that's not true; `nth-child` would work just fine in that case ([proof](https://jsfiddle.net/x6d75m72/1/)). `:nth-child` is just a qualifier like any other: It means "only include this element if it's the Nth child of its parent" **not** "only if it's the Nth item in the match so far."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure to understand everything you say, but take a look at my answer to see where I'm going with this. I agree that an ID should be enough to identify an element, but that requires that the developer made an unique id, which can not be enforced.

Comment: If you can't enforce that, then you can't leave `:nth-child` off your example, either. If you can't know `clients` is only used on one element, you can't know that `div#clients.list.col-md-6` without `:nth-child(3)` is sufficient.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I'm starting to understand where you don't, try to use my above code to get the fourth `div` in my example (so, without the ID tag). And you'll see it's not working.

Comment: Please post an updated fiddle to the comments demonstrating the necessary change to make it not work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I was doing that while you last commented, since it's not clear apparently. Is it better now?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not. Again: Above you told me to change the fiddle in some way and it wouldn't work. Please demonstrate that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Now it should. I've added a jsfiddle and a concrete explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unclear. You said in response to my "proof" fiddle above that there was a change you could make to make it not work. I asked you to make that change. I didn't mean post a fiddle-only link in the question (I meant a response comment). If you want to demonstrate something in the question, which is **great**, please use the built-in Stack Snippets (astonishing to me I hadn't suggest that earlier) via the `[<>]` toolbar button.

Answer (score 0):

> Example : https://jsfiddle.net/an2jsq2r/1/
>
> If you click on the second items, on "Item 3", you'll get :
>
> `body>div.container>div.row:nth-child(1)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(2)`
>
> Which is wrong, because it should be :
>
> `body>div.container>div.row:nth-child(1)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(0)`

No, it shouldn't. You've misunderstood [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). It should be

```
body>div.container>div.row:nth-child(3)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(3)
Note --------------------------------^------------------------------^
```

...because the second `div.row` is the **third** element in its parent, and the first `div.list.col-md-6` in that row is the **third** element in the row.

Here's proof:

```js
var path = "body>div.container>div.row:nth-child(3)>div.list.col-md-6:nth-child(3)";
var element = document.querySelector(path);
element.innerHTML = "This one!";
element.style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I said [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978466/get-the-nth-child-of-the-exact-same-node#comment71138036_41978466), `:nth-child` doesn't care **at all** about the rest of the selector.

Simpler example: `div:nth-child(2)` means "a div which is also the second child in its parent". It does **not** mean "the second div child in its parent."

To determine the correct `:nth-child` to use, you use purely its 1-based index within the parent, with no consideration **at all** of other aspects of it like its tag name, what classes it has, etc.

Consequently, `getIndexInParent` should be:

```
function getIndexInParent(node) {
    var children = node.parentNode.children;    // Note: Not `childNodes`
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // Note: 0 <= n < length
        if (children[i]==node) return i + 1;    // Note: No other criteria, and +1 on value
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If we apply that to your fiddle (this snippet works best if you use the "Full Page" option):

```js
function getPath(e) {
    var path = [];
    if ('path' in e && e.path.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.path.length; i++) {
            if (e.path[i]) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(e.path[i]));
            }
            if (e.path[i] === document.body) break;
        }
    } else {
        var node = e.target;
        while(node != document.body) {
            if (node) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(node));
            }
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }

    path.reverse();
    return path.join('>');
}

function getNodeSignature(node) {
    var structure = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if ('id' in node && node.id) {
        structure += '#' + node.id
    }

    var classes = null;
    if ('classList' in node && node.classList.length > 0) {
        classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.classList);
    } else if ('className' in node && node.className) {
        var classes = node.className.split(/\s+/);
    }

    if (classes !== null && classes.length > 0) {
        structure += '.' + classes.join('.');
    }

    var position = getIndexInParent(node);
    if (position > 0) {
        structure += ':nth-child(' + position + ')';
    }

    return structure;
}

function getIndexInParent(node) {
    var children = node.parentNode.children;    // Note: Not `childNodes`
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // Note: 0 <= n < length
        if (children[i]==node) return i + 1;    // Note: No other criteria, and +1 on value
    }
    return -1;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var path = getPath(e);
  console.log("path is: " + path);
  var element = document.querySelector(path);
  if (element) {
    element.innerHTML = "You clicked me!";
    element.style.color= "green";
    console.log("updated element");
  } else {
    console.log("That's weird, no element found!");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if we apply your `:nth-of-type` idea:

```
function getTypeIndexInParent(node) {
    var tag = node.tagName;
    var children = node.parentNode.children;
    var child;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        child = children[i];
        if (child.tagName === tag) {
            ++num;
        }
        if (children[i]==node) return num;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

We get:

```js
function getPath(e) {
    var path = [];
    if ('path' in e && e.path.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.path.length; i++) {
            if (e.path[i]) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(e.path[i]));
            }
            if (e.path[i] === document.body) break;
        }
    } else {
        var node = e.target;
        while(node != document.body) {
            if (node) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(node));
            }
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }

    path.reverse();
    return path.join('>');
}

function getNodeSignature(node) {
    var structure = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if ('id' in node && node.id) {
        structure += '#' + node.id
    }

    var classes = null;
    if ('classList' in node && node.classList.length > 0) {
        classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.classList);
    } else if ('className' in node && node.className) {
        var classes = node.className.split(/\s+/);
    }

    if (classes !== null && classes.length > 0) {
        structure += '.' + classes.join('.');
    }

    var position = getTypeIndexInParent(node);
    if (position > 0) {
        structure += ':nth-of-type(' + position + ')';
    }

    return structure;
}

function getTypeIndexInParent(node) {
    var tag = node.tagName;
    var children = node.parentNode.children;
    var child;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        child = children[i];
        if (child.tagName === tag) {
            ++num;
        }
        if (children[i]==node) return num;
    }
    return -1;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var path = getPath(e);
  console.log("path is: " + path);
  var element = document.querySelector(path);
  if (element) {
    element.innerHTML = "You clicked me!";
    element.style.color= "green";
    console.log("updated element");
  } else {
    console.log("That's weird, no element found!");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list col-md-3">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list col-md-6">Item 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so I should use nth-of-type instead?

Comment: Maybe the greater goal should up understand what I'm trying to do : If you click on an element on the dom, I need to be able to access it from a generated css selector, from body down to that element. That's why I need to know the exact position in case multiples item are identical.

Comment: And what I can do is the following : I check if there is similar "signature" node (node name + id + classes), if no, I keep that way, if yes, I only use nodeName + nth-of-type. What do you think?

Comment: @CyrilN.: No, `:nth-of-type` doesn't help, because that ignores other qualifiers (like classnames). Just `:nth-child` is what you need, and you need it on every element if you need to apply this to a document you don't know the content of later (you said you couldn't rely on unique IDs, even when I said you could check to see whether they were unique, so that tells me you're using a different document later). Re clicking: It just so happens I was adding an example doing exactly that as you commented! :-)

Comment: (I mean, you could make some reasonable assumptions, like that you don't need it on `html`, `head`, or `body`. :-) )

Comment: Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/33cLdhuj/ I used nth-of-type to keep the node name, because if I use nth-child, I can ignore the node name, right? On my end, this code seems to work correctly.

Comment: Removing head/body/document is the next step ;)

Comment: @CyrilN.: :-) Yes, I shouldn't have said `:nth-of-type` "doesn't help," it absolutely can help if you ensure that the index you use with it ignores other factors like classes. Good point.

Comment: What do you think about this : https://jsfiddle.net/33cLdhuj/1/ ? (The thing is that I want to be as "verbose" as possible : keeping id, class whenever possible, if not, keeping the tag name with its position)

Comment: @CyrilN.: Heh, simultaneous work, I was doing something similar, which is now at the end of the answer. I haven't reviewed the code in the fiddle and have to disappear, but I think this has you on track again. Enjoy!

Comment: We're getting close! Your last example contained an error if the item clicked is the first of the same serie, because of the condition ìf (position > 0)`, it should be `> -1`. Here's a working example (as far as I know) : https://jsfiddle.net/33cLdhuj/2/

Comment: I don't understand the issue, `> 0` vs. `> -1` doesn't matter when the function never returns `0` (which it doesn't).

Comment: Final draft : https://jsfiddle.net/33cLdhuj/4/ For the -1 vs 0, I suspect I mixed your code with mine, and it resulted with invalid result.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so in order to use the ":nth-of-type" only when necessary, this means only when the other rules (node name + node id + node classes) are the same for at least 2 childrens.

Here's the result :

```
function getIndexInParent(node) {
    if (node === null || node.parentNode === null) return -1;

    var children = node.parentNode.childNodes,
        freezePosition = false,
        position = 1,  // 1 based index
        quantity = 1; // Already counting the same item
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (node === children[i]) {
            freezePosition = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (node.nodeName === children[i].nodeName) {
            if (!freezePosition) position++;
            quantity++;
        }
    }

    return (quantity > 1 ? position : -1);
}

function getNodeSignature(node, withoutPosition) {
    if (!node || !node.nodeName) return null;

    var structure = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    if (withoutPosition !== false) {
        var position = getIndexInParent(node);
        if (position > 0) {
            return structure + ':nth-of-type(' + position + ')';
        }
    }

    if ('id' in node && node.id) {
        structure += '#' + node.id
    }

    var classes = null;
    if ('classList' in node && node.classList.length > 0) {
        classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.classList);
    } else if ('className' in node && node.className) {
        var classes = node.className.split(/\s+/);
    }

    if (classes !== null && classes.length > 0) {
        structure += '.' + classes.join('.');
    }

    return structure;
}

function getPath(e) {
    var path = [];
    if ('path' in e && e.path.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.path.length; i++) {
            if (e.path[i] === window.document || e.path[i] === window.document.body) break;
            if (e.path[i]) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(e.path[i]));
            }
        }
    } else {
        var node = e.target;
        while(true) {
            if (node === window.document || node === window.document.body) break;
            if (node) {
                path.push(getNodeSignature(node));
            }
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }

    if (path.length > 0) {
        path.reverse();
        return 'body>' + path.join('>');
    }

    return null;
}
```

If someone has better, I'm curious to see how :)

Comment: `:nth-child` doesn't care, at all, about the signature of the node it refers to. The signature is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Tested with jQuery, and it seems it does. Do you have the documentation to proove otherwise?

Comment: Ok, you're right about it, so maybe I can only use the nth-child.